# Re-login command?

Tags: login

There is already rebooting, but sometimes, I would just like to automatically relogin to prepare quickly for carrying a laptop without needing to wait the logout to finish in order to re-login manually, to start a fresh session and quit all battery-consuming applications.

Is there a re-login command?

Comment: Can't you just lock the screen?

Comment: @Kusalananda That does not refresh the session. Reboot = Shutdown+Boot. I want relogin=logout+login in a single step.

Comment: This may help. [How to Refresh Your Linux Desktop Without Rebooting][1]

  [1]: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/refresh-linux-desktop-without-rebooting/

Comment: Any attempt to log out then log in, would ask to enter your password, however this will cause a delay which you don't want. I assume what you are asking for is how to setup an `auto login` if so this relies on your system e.g. in ubuntu check the user account dialog box which provide an `auto login` option! Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @Goro What I was looking for was resetting my session and closing… oh wait. While I was writing this: I think I could just end tasks without logging out. And restarting tasks would consume battery anyway. Still, thank you Goro.

Comment: Hello, @frams. Thank you for the article link.